# Какие преимущества даёт функция pack()?

Tags: php

По учёбе читаю "Алгоритмы и структуры даннах" Н.Вирта. Там попалась инфа о том, что мелкие данные можно упаковывать в одно слово. Как я понял это позволяет более рационально использовать память.  Возможно это относится только к низкоуровневым языкам.

Так что возник вопрос: какие преимущества даёт функция pack() и что интересного можно сделать с бинарной строкой полученной на выходе? Так как вопрос явно школьного уровня лучше дайте ссылку на статью в тему.

**UPD:** перечитал и понял, что какой-то бред спросил. Потому галочка+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вы не в состоянии набрать два слова в Гугл?

Одна из первых: [pack](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pack.php)

> Упаковывает заданные аргументы в бинарную строку согласно формату в параметре *format*.

Comment: На мой взгляд, рано закрыли вопрос. Так как меня интересует не то, что делает сама функция, а то, что можно сделать с полученной от неё бинарной строкой.

Comment: Google "php pack примеры" выдает

     Результатов: примерно 10 400 000 (0,18 сек.)

Читайте.